# Make Closure Compiler merge several object property declarations as one big literal

Tags: javascript, properties, google-closure-compiler, object-literal, minify

I split my code into several files, and then run a script to merge and compile them (with `ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS`). A big part of the functionality is implemented in a **single object's prototype**.

So when merged, it could look something like this:

```
(function(){

/** @constructor */ function MyConstructor() {};

MyConstructor.prototype = {};

MyConstructor.prototype['foo'] = function() { alert('foo'); };
MyConstructor.prototype['bar'] = function() { alert('bar'); };
MyConstructor.prototype['baz'] = function() { alert('baz'); };

window['MyConstructor'] = MyConstructor;

}());
```

If you put that code into [Closure Compiler](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home) just like that, here's the output (pretty-printed):

```
function a() {
}
a.prototype = {};
a.prototype.foo = function() {
  alert("foo")
};
a.prototype.bar = function() {
  alert("bar")
};
a.prototype.baz = function() {
  alert("baz")
};
window.MyConstructor = a;
```

The question is, is there some way I could tell Closure Compiler that it's ok to **merge all of these in a single object literal**, and even if there was code in-between (in this example there isn't, but there could be), so that no matter what, it made it all compile into one big object literal?

Here's a couple of solutions, and why they wouldn't work for me:

- **Solution 1:** Simply declare them in one big object literal.
  **Wouldn't work** because I have my code into several files, and I plan to make it so users can remove some of them (if they don't need them) prior to compilation. Object literals have comma-delimiters that would make this a nightmare.
- **Solution 2**: Declare all functionality outside of the object (as private variables in the closure), and attach them into a simplified object literal at the end, which just has references to properties (such as `{'foo':foo,'bar':bar,'baz':baz}`).
  **Wouldn't work** because, as said, the idea is to create something modular, and removing one file would make the reference break.

I'm open to ideas!

---

**Edit:** Some people could think that Closure Compiler can't do this. It can do this and much more, it's just that it has a bad attitude and does things when it feels like it.

Input this into Closure:

```
(function(){

var MyConstructor = window['MyConstructor'] = function() {};

var myProto = {
    'foo': function() { alert('foo'); },
    'bar': function() { alert('bar'); }
};

myProto['baz'] = function() { alert('baz'); };

MyConstructor.prototype = myProto;

}());
```

The result is:

```
(window.MyConstructor = function() {
}).prototype = {foo:function() {
  alert("foo")
}, bar:function() {
  alert("bar")
}, baz:function() {
  alert("baz")
}};
```

See? But, this is code is very fragile in that it may compile into something completely different (and not that good) if modified slightly. For example even a variable assignment somewhere in the middle might cause it to output very different results. In other words, this doesn't work (except in this case).

---

**Edit 2:** see this [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/object-literals-vs-object-properties). A big object literal is faster in Chrome (proportional to its size).

---

**Edit 3:** [Closure Compiler bug report](http://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/issues/detail?id=829).

Comment: @wvxvw Closure is very different from regular minifiers, it is really a compiler. It does things that go way beyond what others do, at least with `ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS` on. What I mean is that it already did many other much more complicated things that could potentially have broken my javascripts severely (and sometimes did, luckily I have unit tests to know when that happens). Also, there is a case in my code when Closure compiler DOES exactly this! I'll edit with an example.

Comment: @wvxvw It's not bad. There are three compilation modes. One removes `WHITESPACE_ONLY` (super safe), the other does `SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS` (the kind of thing that should be safe in 99% of cases, think YUI compiler), and the one I like is when it does `ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS`, in other words, there's a high chance it will break your code unless you're very careful, but on the upside, the code runs faster, and is waaay smaller than what your garden-variety minifier could do.

Comment: Why do you *want* it to be assigned using a single object literal syntax? Is it because of file size? If so, are you gzipping? If you are, I'm guessing that it won't make any difference.

Comment: @user1689607 I'm gzipping (in any case this is a library), but it's not only because of file size, there should be a small performance gain. I mean, compare creating an empty object and setting properties on it one by one, against just creating it once, with all properties set. It should be faster to create it only once. A bit of informal benchmarking on my part seems to confirm this, in Chrome.

Comment: @CamiloMartin: With all due respect, I certainly believe you that a direct comparison of the two approaches shows a single object assignment to be faster than an empty object assignment followed by multiple property assignments, but if you compare the entire loading of the library given the two approaches, I'd have a hard time believing that the difference is perceptible. If this were some code that needed to run multiple times in rapid succession, those minor optimizations may be worthwhile, but for a one-time operation, I wouldn't spend too much time trying to outsmart the compiler.

Comment: Not that I'm trying to minimize your question. But I've spent enough time trying to tweak my code for Closure Compiler to know that it has rarely made any real difference.

Comment: @user1689607 Well, your point does make sense, I guess it's a bit of stubbornness. If I can't find a way, I'll give up on it and just make it property assignments.

Comment: @wvxvw Do you mean how jsPerf works? It executes the code several times (like, in this case, thousands), so it makes a more or less representative average. There's no need to write the benchmark loops themselves with jsPerf, since it does that already. You might want to read its [FAQ](http://jsperf.com/faq), or check out the engine it uses, [Benchmark.js](http://benchmarkjs.com/).

Comment: @wvxvw Well, the idea is to benchmark speeds. I understand that faster code might not be better code (sometimes it can be buggy or harder to mantain), but it is possible to measure its speed. It has the advantage of being an objective metric, and objectiveness sometimes creeps into places where a qualitative measure would be better. I won't say that's not the case with my micro-optimization effort...

Comment: @wvxvw Well, the number is in operations per second. So each snippet is ran (possibly with setup/teardown) in a loop, until it can average some stable number of operations per second. The bigger the number, the faster the code runs. If one item says "10% slower", it means "10% slower than the fastest snippet" - the idea is to compare similar code and see which one should be used based on speed (assuming they work the same or are compatible for a certain case).

Comment: You are correct in that the compiler does not do this optimizations currently. Can you post a feature request (and be sure to reference your jsperf results)? http://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/issues/list

Comment: @ChadKillingsworth Yes, I'll do that and post a link here.

Comment: @wvxvw Well, I wouldn't say JsPerf is silly - if you have two chunks of code (potentially very big code, if you include a library), it can easily tell you which one runs faster. What I don't understand is why you say it isn't comparing them to one another, for me it is. For example, a result like this: `767,727
±8.03%
61% slower` means that a certain snippet runs at some 767,727 operations per second, within a 8% error margin, and is 61% slower than the fastest snippet.

Comment: @wvxvw Well, faster than the other snippet(s). So if you know know five ways of doing the same thing, you make five snippets, and run the test. The one which says "fastest" is the fastest one. (I can't see the word "faster" in the page, there's just "fastest" and "slower").

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround I'm doing. It might not apply, so this answer cannot be accepted. Still, this is what works in my case.

My folder structure looked like this:

```
src
├───components
└───core
```

And, before compilation, I merged `src/intro.js`, some files at the `src` level (in a specific order), then all of the files in `core` (any order), then all in `components` (any order), then `outro.js`.

Now, the folder structure looks like this:

```
src
├───components
│   ├───modules
│   └───plugs-literal
└───core
    ├───internal
    ├───modules
    └───plugs-literal
```

And the compilation order is (note the part with arrows):

- `src/intro.js`
- a couple files in `src/core`, specific order.
- All files in `src/core/internal`
- `src/core/plugs-literal-intro.js` **<--**
- All files in `src/core/plugs-literal` **<--**
- All files in `src/components/plugs-literal` **<--**
- `src/core/plugs-literal-outro.js` **<--**
- All files in `src/core/modules`
- All files in `src/components/modules`
- `src/outro.js`

The idea is that one file contains the beginning of an object literal, another file has the closing of an object literal, and two folders contain properties. More or less like this:

#### `src/core/plugs-literal-intro.js`:

```
var myObjectLiteral = {
    'someSimpleProp': 'foo',
    'someOtherSimpleProp': 'bar',
    'lastOneWithoutTrailingComma': 'baz'
```

#### `src/core/plugs-literal/EXAMPLE.js`:

```
,'example': function() { alert('example'); } // comma before, not after.
```

#### `src/core/plugs-literal-outro.js`:

```
};
```

If this introduces some unwanted problem, I'll know later. But then, I could assign a different folder to contain prototype properties declared individually.